# Need suggestions on a tool to measure the difference in memory usage (runtime) between two versions of code

Tags: c, memory, profiling, valgrind

I have a structure which contains a char* that contains encoded/compressed binary data. A function decodes and uncompresses this binary function into a nested structure of the first structure. Simplified structure definitions below:

```
typedef struct {
    int count;
    float X-data;
    float Y-data;
} spectra;
typedef struct {
    int count;
    char* binary;
    int binary_length;
    spectrum* spectra
} chrom;
```

My first version of the program only freed the memory allocated to the char* at the end of the program but yesterday i realized i can free it directly after decoding/uncompressing.

I then tried comparing the difference in terms of performance with Valgrind but that lists total memory allocated by the program, which remains the same obviously. I would like to know how much memory i now have available (extra) for the calculations itself since i have to store less data in my memory while the program is running.

Does anyone have any good tools/suggestions for me on how to measure this?

Thanks in Advance.